# Rails find data from association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't know if the title of the question is correct.

I have  `locations`, `hardware`, and `hardware_type` tables but no nested routes.
I have set up the relationships so that `location` has_many `hardware`s and `hardware` belongs_to `hardware_categories` along with the reciprocal relationships.

In my locations controller in the show action I have

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /locations
# GET /locations.json
def index
   @locations = Location.all
end

 # GET /locations/1
 # GET /locations/1.json
 def show
   @hardwares = Hardware.where(:location_id => params[:id])
 end
```

And in my show page

```
<% @hardwares.each do |hardware| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= hardware.name %></td>
    <td><%= hardware.asset_tag %></td>
    <td><%= hardware.serial_number %></td>
    <td><%= hardware.note  %></td>
    <td><%= hardware.hardware_category_id  %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This works and the `hardware.hardware_category_id` returns the correct number.

I would like to show the name of the `hardware_category` instead

I thought something like

```
<td><%= hardware.hardware_category_id.name  %></td>
```

would work but I get `undefined method 'name' for 1:Fixnum`
How would I get access to this data

schema

```
create_table "hardware_categories", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "hardwares", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "asset_tag"
  t.string   "serial_number"
  t.text     "description"
  t.text     "note"
  t.string   "cost"
  t.date     "purchase_date"
  t.date     "warranty_end_date"
  t.date     "eol"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "mdl"
  t.integer  "location_id"
  t.integer  "hardware_category_id"
  t.integer  "manufacturer_id"
  t.integer  "supplier_id"
end
```

Comment: It seems you are new to Rails.It's very basic thing you should first try before directly putting to the stack overflow.

Comment: @punitcse I am new to rails. I thought it was going to be more complicated. I tried most combinations of the .notation excepy the one that worked. I was on the thinking that we needed to get to the other table via the id feild rather then it already been available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= hardware.hardware_category.name  %>` Is what you need.

No need for the `_id`. The name of the association is as you defined it in the model. I assume its something like:

`belongs_to :hardware_category`

I recommend reading this guide, before you try doing much more rails. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

The reason you are seeing that error, is because the `hardware_category_id` is exactly that, an Integer(FixNum) and the FixNum class doesn't have a method/attribute called `name`.

--

*Rich Peck edit*

A better way to do this will be to use [`.try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) to evaluate whether the corresponding `hardware_category` exists...

```
<%= hardware.hardware_category.try(:name) %>
```

... this will prevent any "not found" errors if the corresponding object is non existent.

Answer (score 0):

`hardware.hardware_category_id.name` finds the `hardware_category_id`, then you find the name of that id.

In this case `hardware.hardware_category_id == 1`.

So you are calling `1.name` and as 1 is a fixnum, and doesn't have the method name, you are getting the undefined method `name` for `1:Fixnum error`.

You could create a new field in hardware called `hardware_category_name` and then call `hardware.hardware_category_name`.